# Named Ranges in power point

Tags: date, drop-down-menu, powerpoint

I am attempting to create two drop down lists in power point, a "From date" and a  "To date". I wish these drop down menu to contain dates, ordinarily in VBA you would create a named range. How do you do it in Power point?  I literally have no idea?!

I have started with the basics:

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
 If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
 AddDropDownItems
  End If
  End Sub

Sub AddDropDownItems()
ComboBox1.AddItem "1"
ComboBox1.AddItem "2"
ComboBox1.AddItem "3"
ComboBox1.ListRows = 3
End Sub
```

Comment: PowerPoint has nothing like Excel's named ranges. But what exactly is your question? You clearly know how to populate a combo box ... is it a question of where to get the data to populate it with or ???

Comment: I know how to populate the box, yes, but writing lots of date seems very inefficient! How do I get the data into the box smoothly? Where can I hold a lot of data and make it available?

Comment: Do you know of any websites on making interactive power point sheets? Ultimately I wish these dates to control dynamic graphs. Is such a think possible?

Comment: "How do I get the data" is too open-ended to tackle. Can you be more specific?  Where is the data now?  Do you need to pull it from a spreadsheet, database or is it on a yellow pad?  Will the data change frequently or is it pretty much a set list?

Comment: Two sources: Excel and SQL. Can I read a named range from excel in power point?

Comment: You can automate Excel from within PowerPoint, so if you can read a named range from within Excel, the same code, with a few modifications, should work within PPT.